# Can g(n) be same for big O and omega notation for f(n)

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I have been studying asymptotic notation and I understand that in big O notation $f(n) <=c1*g(n)$ and in omega notation we have $f(n)>= c2*g(n)$ where $c1$ and $c2$ are some constant.

Now I was wondering if the function $g(n)$ here are the same and the big O and omega of $f(n)$ is determined by constants $c1$ and $c2$. Or if the $g(n)$ is different for O and omega.

If $g(n)$ is indeed same can anyone explain with example how is it possible as I can think of the examples in which $g(n)$ is different in both cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You seem to be confusing big-O notation and its definition. "In big O notation f(n) <=O( c1*g(n))" doesn't make any sense: I think you mean that "$f(n)=O(g(n))$ means that $f(n)\leq c_1\,g(n)$" (for large enough $n$). But I don't know what you mean by asking if the function $g(n)$ is the same. Big-O is a lot like "less than" for functions. So your question is a bit like saying, "I know what $x<a$ means and what $x>a$ means. But is it the same $a$?"

Comment: In particular, you can say that $x\leq 10$ and $xleq4$ but that doesn't mean that $4=10$. But you can also say $x\geq6$ and $x\leq6$.  (I should really have used $\leq$ in my first comment.)

Comment: If you have $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$, then the $g$'s are the same function (since you wrote it that way). On the other hand, if (unknown to you) you had $f(n)=n^2$, then it would be correct to say $f(n)=O(n^3)$ and $f(n)=\Omega(n)$, with different functions on the right.

Comment: Yes, here if g(n) is the same function does upper and lower bound of f(n) then depend on c1 and c2.

Comment: Not in general. To say, for instance, $f(n)=O(g(n))$ means that there is some $c>0$ and $N>0$ such that $f(n)\le c\,g(n)$ for all $n\ge N$. There are lots of choices for $c$: if you knew $f(n)\le c_1\,g(n)$ then certainly $f(n)\le c_2\,g(n)$ for *any* $c_2\ge c_1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you write down $f \in O(g)$ and $f \in \Omega(g)$ then you clearly intend both instances of "$g$" to refer to the same function. Otherwise, it would be pretty confusing.

Note how this is equivalent to $f \in \Theta(g)$.

If, however, you write down $f \in O(n^2)$ and $f \in \Omega(n)$ and want to unfold both the definition of $O$ and $\Omega$, you'll have to instantiate two different "$g$"s. That is, you'd write

$\qquad c_1 g_1(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_2 g_2(n)$

for all $n \geq n_0$ for some $c_1, c_2 > 0$ and $n_0 \geq 0$. Here, we know that $g_1 = n \mapsto n$ and $g_2 = n \mapsto n^2$.